# ros_canopen dcf_overlay setting

Tags: ros, can, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using **ros_canopen** to control my robot.

The joint_position_controller works but I get stuck with **joint_trajectory_controller**.
I set PDO mapping through **dcf_overlay** :

```
dcf_overlay:
    "1600sub0": "2"
    "1600sub1": "0x60400010" # map Control Word to RPDO1
    "1600sub2": "0x60c10120" # map 60c1sub2(position for PVT mode) to RPDO1
    "1601sub0": "2"
    "1601sub1": "0x60400010" # map Control Word to RPDO2
    "1601sub2": "0x60600008" # map 0x6060(mode of operation) to RPDO2
    "60c0": "0x0000" # map Interpolation submode 0:Linear interpolation with constant time
```

The candump message confused me because:

```
$ candump can0 -dcex |grep 201 # candump RPDO1
   can0  TX - -  201   [6]  04 00 AA 32 00 00
$ candump can0 -dcex |grep 301 # candump RPDO2
   can0  TX - -  301   [3]  1F 01 07 # halt the drive?
   can0  TX - -  301   [3]  1F 00 07
   can0  TX - -  301   [3]  1F 01 07  # halt the drive?
   can0  TX - -  301   [3]  1F 00 07
   ...
```

1.How come the first two bytes of the RPDO1 message differ with that of RPDO2 since they both are mapped to **control word**?

2.`$ candump can0 -dcex |grep 201` showed that the position data were successfully sent to CAN bus. But the robot didn't move. Control word **1F 01** seems to be **halting the drive** and indicates the operation mode is **profile position mode**(see [Copley Manual](http://www.copleycontrols.com/Motion/pdf/CANopenProgrammersManual.pdf) P58). Is it a problem?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250969/ros_canopen-dcf_overlay-setting/) by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2016-12-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mapping an object to multiple PDOs is not supported (https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/183).
Each object can only be mapped once, not even twice within the same PDO.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2016-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-12-30**:
Thank you. Now I've changed the PDO mappings(github.com/Linkeway/BIRL_modular_robot/blob/master/birl_module_canopen/config/manipulator5d_motors.yaml).`abort60c1#1, reason: Invalid value for parameter (download only)` showed up during initialization. I set DefaultValue for 60c1#1 in dcf. No luck.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-12-30**:
candump showed

```
can0  TX - -  601   [8]  23 C1 60 01 00 00 00 00
can0  RX - -  581   [8]  80 C1 60 01 30 00 09 06
```

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-12-30**:
Looks like your PDO mapping was not applied correctly.
Please fix  doubled object in https://github.com/Linkeway/BIRL_modular_robot/blob/master/birl_module_canopen/config/manipulator5d_motors.yaml#L28
And all other doubled configs.

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-12-30**:
In addition your DCF is wrong: https://github.com/Linkeway/BIRL_modular_robot/blob/master/birl_module_canopen/config/birl_copley.dcf#L31
It even misses the 140x entries.

Please use **CANeds**

And: using the Schunk DCF as a template might be error prone, too!

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-12-31**:
You are right. I used the Schunk DCF because the Copley eds was faulty. I use a modified Copley eds now, and initialization produces:

```
[ERROR]:canopen_master/src/pdo.cpp(372): Throw in function void canopen::PDOMapper::Buffer::write(const canopen::ObjectDict::Entry&, const canopen::String&)
```

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-12-31**:
Dynamic exception type:      boost::exception_detail::clone_implboost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::bad_cast >
std::exception::what: std::bad_cast
[canopen::tag_objectdict_key*] = 60c1sub1

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-12-31**:
Your DCF contains a wrong object type for 60c1, please use CANeds to validate your DCF against 301 and 402 standard and fix all warnings.

Update: The object type should work as well, not sure why you get the size mismatch..